# JavaScript array filtering embedded object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

how to filter array embedded object array?
I use filter and some, but the result is not my though.

```
var data = [
  {
    "app": "mail",
    "scenarios": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "description": "plugin 1",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "001",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "app2",
        "description": "plugin 2",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "002",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "app": "mail2",
    "scenarios": [
      {
        "name": "app1",
        "description": "plugin 1",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "001",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "app2",
        "description": "plugin 2",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "002",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

result = data.filter(app => app.scenarios.some(scenario => scenario.contacts.some(concact => concact.resourceId == '001')));
```

I want to filter the data to

```
[
  {
    "app": "mail",
    "scenarios": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "description": "plugin 1",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "001",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "app": "mail2",
    "scenarios": [
      {
        "name": "app1",
        "description": "plugin 1",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "001",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```js
var data = [{"app":"mail","scenarios":[{"name":"","description":"plugin 1","contacts":[{"resourceId":"001","isPrimary":false}]},{"name":"app2","description":"plugin 2","contacts":[{"resourceId":"002","isPrimary":false}]}]},{"app":"mail2","scenarios":[{"name":"app1","description":"plugin 1","contacts":[{"resourceId":"001","isPrimary":false}]},{"name":"app2","description":"plugin 2","contacts":[{"resourceId":"002","isPrimary":false}]}]}];

result = data.filter(app => app.scenarios.some(scenario => scenario.contacts.some(concact => concact.resourceId == '001')));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to filter the `scenarios` array and `contacts` array both. If you want to get a scenario which has at least one contact with `resourceId === "001"` you could do the following.

```js
let data = [
  {
    "app": "mail",
    "scenarios": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "description": "plugin 1",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "001",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "app2",
        "description": "plugin 2",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "002",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "app": "mail2",
    "scenarios": [
      {
        "name": "app1",
        "description": "plugin 1",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "001",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "app2",
        "description": "plugin 2",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "002",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
 
for(let item of data) {
   item.scenarios = item.scenarios.filter(value => {
      let validContacts = value.contacts.filter(contact => {
         return contact.resourceId === "001";
      })

      return validContacts.length > 0;
   })
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
  {
    "app": "mail",
    "scenarios": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "description": "plugin 1",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "001",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "app2",
        "description": "plugin 2",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "002",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "app": "mail2",
    "scenarios": [
      {
        "name": "app1",
        "description": "plugin 1",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "001",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "app2",
        "description": "plugin 2",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "resourceId": "002",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

data.forEach(dat => {
 dat.scenarios = dat.scenarios.find(da => da.contacts.find(x=>x.resourceId === "001"));
});

console.log(data)
```

You can go thru the code see if it fits what you're looking. An assumption made which `contacts` array will only have one element. Let me know if it's otherwise

Comment: This is work, but contacts might be a object array, so using da.contacts[0] I think is not good for this case.

Comment: @user3206091: Updated, kindly check, basically just instead of using index 0, apply a find function to it